# Here SDK tile activity indicator

Tags: here-api

The Here SDK for android contains callback methods (MapEngine.OnMapDownloadListener) indicating when a tile(s) is being downloaded, how do I do this in iOS?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry seems this was not exposed on iOS. The protocol is hidden and not in our header files.